# How to remove next commits

Tags: git, git-commit

I've done some commits at my repository that I want to remove. I've come back to the commit which I want to preserve:

```
$ git checkout commit_hash_num
```

How should I proceed to remove the next commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just

```
git reset --hard commit_hash_num
```

Fair Warning:

- this does *really* modify your branch's HEAD to refer to the old commit
- this loses any local, uncommitted changes

---

Don't worry too much, though: you can always immediately go back:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

in case you get second thoughts with respect to those later commits. Or, maybe:

```
git checkout -v save_wrong_commits_branch HEAD@{1}
```

to get back the dropped commits on a spearate branch with an apt name :/